# How to prevent my dog drool

Tags: dogs, psychology, grooming

My 6 year Beagle is *almost* perfect pet- he rarely barks, is very playful and fairly obedient

All that goes for a toss when it is *feeding time*. He drools so much in anticipation of being fed, and leaves pools of drool puddles all over. It is not that he isn't being fed enough- he is almost always a step away from obese. I am pretty sure he can't stop eating till he is physically unable to !

I kind of hoped that this drooling would decrease with age but on the contrary, it seems to increase

I know it is involuntary but cleaning after him is taking a toll. Vets I have talked to couldn't  offer any help

Would love to hear from folks here (PS: That's him on my Avatar)

Comment: Websearching "beagle drooling" suggests that it isn't uncommon, may just be excited thoughts of food.... But if it happens when _not_ eating it could be an indication of disease

Comment: @keshlam: Thanks. It doesn't happen when not eating. Guess it's something we have to accept- had a variety of dogs over last three decades but it never was a problem

Comment: My neighbour's dog (8 year old golden retriever) does that a lot ( I mean a LOT of drooling) when he sees us eating or before it is fed while my dog doesn't. I think it is natural for some kinds of  dogs. I don't know about beagles, though...